# Safari users unable to connect to website with SSL Certifiacte enabled

Tags: ssl, iis-7, safari

We are having issues with our SSL IIS certificate on our site and the ability of Safari browser users being able to access it.
Our Web site is hosted on Windows 2008 server with IIS7.
Our SSL certificate is issued by Network Solutions and tests successfully with an SSLchecker on the web.
We have SOME Safari users that cannot connect to our site with the SSL Certificate enabled.
Users are getting a "No certificate available" or a "Confirm Certifiate" message when users access from Safari.
We do have some safari users for instance on an IPhone that can access ok from Safari version 6.0.4.
Posts are suggesting to set the server to accept all certificates or to set OSCP and CRL to be disabled on the Mac OS.
Our website is on IIS7 and Most Mac users are running OS 10.7.5 (Lion) Windows Safari users also have this issue.
Does anyone have any insight to this? Any suggestions would be appresiated.

Comment: There's a bunch of different SSL Checkers on the web. When [I was having problems configuring an SSL cert](http://serverfault.com/q/449369/39133) I found that [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) gave me a lot more information than most of the others. Try that and see what it tells you. (See "Test Your SSL Server Now!" on the bottom left of that page.)

Comment: Thank you for your post and information on that one. I hadn't seen that before. I did see more detailed information.

Comment: Yeah. You saw more detailed information. If you pass that information on to us ([edit] your question), we might be able to help you.